# PHP Composer ignore prompt and Force Update

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php

I have automated autoscale AWS environment and using Amazon Code Deploy to deploy my code from bitbucket once the code has been deployed I have an AfterInstall script which runs

```
composer update
```

But occasionally I noticed that it stops and prompts for certain changes like

> The package has modified files:
>
> ```
> Discard changes [y,n,v,d,s,?]?
> ```

My question is how can I force the update because most of the time the file changes are related to minor permission issues, and my server returns a failed deployment error after hitting that prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found the solution. Its rather in the help of composer.

```
 composer update --no-interaction
```